# Looping throgh json jinja2 python

Tags: python, json, django, jinja2

I have a json fron an API like this:

[image]

my views.py looks like this:

```
def index(request):
    movieData = requests.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=Ishtar&api_key=....').json()

    return render(request, 'dashboard/index.html', {'movieData': movieData})
```

My html looks like this:

```
{% for item in movieData %}
  <lu>
    <li>
      {{ item.results.id }}
    </li>
  </lu>
{% endfor %}
```

However the loop is not working, it's not getting the data, this is how it looks:

[image]

Can someone give me hand please? I'm learning.

I'm trying to get the id of the 4 movies on the json result

Many thanks

Comment: Are those 4 ids in results array? Or do u want to iterate through results array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct answer:

```
{% for item in movieData.results %} 
    <li>{{ item.id }}</li> 
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be iterating over the right thing. The array is inside results.

```
{% for item in movieData.results %}
    <li>{% item.id %}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: you're answer is partially correct. Based on it I was able to do it. It would be like this: {% for item in movieData.results %}
    <li>{{ item.id }}</li>
{% endfor %} please fix it to mark it as the right answer

Many thanks